# Can't link HTML to CSS on my system

Tags: hyperlink

Help. Am learning HTML5/CSS. Things are going spiffy until I cannot debug my HTML/CSS markup.

Am using WeBuilder which auto-completes and has links to standard tools like Tidy and others.
Here is what I’ve tried

1. used an internal CSS link in my HTML: it works;
2. put the styles.css in same and in a css folder- BUMMER
3. have relocated both files to another HDD- BUMMER
4. both files validate with my available tools

I am sure the problem is in the HTML file and have fiddled with every modification I can find suggestions about. I have rewritten the HTML again using WeBuilder’s auto complete but have not done it in Notepad. I understand the basics of HTML and CSS plus am  very familiar with files and folders so have directed the href correctly (even so have tried several ideas from W3C.

**NOTE:** I see in the "publish" here, it picks up the Arial font where mine has times. If Arial is not your default, I'm at a loss because the color doesn't show. Neither shows the color. If I can be of further help please advise. I really thank you for any help.

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>A Simple Page</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/htm; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <style type="text/css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
      </style>
  </head>
      <body>
      <h1>First Title</h1>
      <p>A paragraph of interesting content</p>
      <h2>Second Title</h2>
      <p>A paragraph of interesting content</p>
      <h2>Third Title</h2>
      <p>A paragraph of interesting content</p>
      </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
h1, h2 {
  color: #3366CC;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: try removing the style tags, and just doing `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` , if that don't work, try using the full url

Answer (score 2):

This makes no sense:

```
<style type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</style>
```

It should simply be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

The `<style>` tags are only used for inline CSS in a page. So if you wanted to you could do this:

```
<style type="text/css">
h1, h2 {
    color: #3366CC;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

But it is really better to keep CSS in a separate file.

Also, there is a minor issue with your `DOCTYPE` at the top of your HTML file. An HTML5 `DOCTYPE` is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
```

The purpose of HTML5 is to—among other things—simplify document formatting & readability. So there is no such thing as `<!DOCTYPE html5>` it is simply `<!DOCTYPE html>`.